# Updating a table by fetching table name from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Suppose i have a master table (TEST) which stores names of various tables like

```
ID | TABLE_NAME
1  | TABLE_1
2  | TABLE_2
3  | TABLE_3
```

Now I want to update tables like this

```
update (
   select TABLE_NAME 
   from TEST 
   where id =1 
 ) t set t.(some attribute) = 'XYZ';
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your syntax should work, with a few slight changes:

```
UPDATE (SELECT some_col FROM TEST WHERE id = 1)
SET some_col = 'XYZ';
```

You need to expose the columns you wish to be update by adding them to the select clause of the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PL/SQL block /procedure to do that with  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

```
DECLARE
     v_value   VARCHAR2(10) := 'XYZ';
BEGIN
     FOR t IN (
          SELECT table_name
          FROM test --where condition
     ) LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || r.table_name || ' 
        SET some_attribute = :somevalue'
               USING v_value;
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```